# object has no method 'createProxyServer' meteor crash

Tags: meteor

i installed meteor and i want test an exemple , so i create test app but when i launch it (>>meteor) i get this error

> "object has no method 'create proxy server'"

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6rMm.png)

i even tryed to uninstall and reinstall meteor , updating and reset ,but still getting this error .
thnx for help.

rq: i used meteor before with no such problem but this my first time on this PC.

Comment: Make sure you on `meteor@1.3.2.4`, there was a [bug in v1.3.2.3](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/commit/4e81417281a371ad93f9191dfc3bfaf7f6cb7124#commitcomment-17224433)

Comment: actually i'am using meteor@1.3.2.4 :\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem and could solve it by deleting the **http-proxy** folder in **%USERPROFILE%\node_modules** (see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-talk/wYQ8RUkXPxA). There was a global installed version of http-proxy that uses the main branch. But meteor needs the "caronte" branch of this repo. After deleting it I just ran `meteor npm install` and `meteor` and everything was working as expected.